# jQuery Timepicker-Addon don't show correct time format

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, time-format

I got stuck with [jQuery Timepicker-Addon](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) on display time format text and I need your help.

The scenario is simple. I have a list of time format; when I change time format, the `datetimepicker` change the format according to.

The `datetimepicker` work well with format from Year -> Minute. But when I set time format to `hh:mm:ss`, `hh:mm:ss.SSS`, `datetimepicker` only show minute unit.

I set `timeFormat` in `beforeShow` event but its seem `timepicker-addon` have default `timeformat` and I cannot override inside `beforeShow`.

To summarize, when I choose format

> - YYYY -> 2016 --> `OK`
> - YYYY/MM -> 2016/07 --> `OK`
> - ...
> - hh:mm -> 2016/07/23 17:05 --> `OK`
> - hh:mm:ss -> 2016/07/23 17:05 **--x-->** Expect: 2016/07/23 17:05:10
> - mm:ss.SSS -> 2016/07/23 17:05 **--x-->** Expect: 2016/07/23 17:05:10 123

Here is my codepen: http://codepen.io/manhle/pen/AXaWYj

Please point me out where I was missing.

Thanks in advances.

References: https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon/issues/56

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `timeFormat` in setting doesn't effect to `timepicker`, just effect to `datepicker`.

So, I need to change default time format of `timepicker` by add this line inside `beforeShow` event.

```
instance.settings.timepicker._defaults.timeFormat = timeFormat;
```